# How to change persist level in Spark machine learning example.

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm doing some benchmark to replay experiments of some famous papers.

To do that, I'm using examples bundled with spark source and using some command like below to execute logistic regression.

> ./bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 6g --conf "spark.memory.fraction=0.6" examples/src/main/python/mllib/logistic_regression.py svm.txt 100

However, I want to change intermediate data's storage level(like persistent MEMORY_ONLY or DISK_ONLY) but couldn't find out way.
I checked logistic_regression.py, classification.py and common.py but these files doesn't hold any code for persistent or cache for intermediate data.

Can you tell me where to is the file to fix? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, it does. If you look in the code. You can persist the rdd:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: logistic_regression <file> <iterations>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonLR")
    points = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1]).map(parsePoint)
    # persist rdd
    points.persist(pyspark.StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
```

Comment: Oh, so there was no cache or persist in the original code after all. Foolish me. I thought there was cache or persistence somewhere because it said something like 
////////17/07/12 17:36:47 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_5_24 in memory! (computed 29.6 MB so far)
17/07/12 17:36:47 INFO MemoryStore: Memory use = 441.9 MB (blocks) + 73.9 MB (scratch space shared across 2 tasks(s)) = 515.9 MB. Storage limit = 516.1 MB. 
17/07/12 17:36:47 WARN BlockManager: Persisting block rdd_5_24 to disk instead. /////////
again and again. Thank you!